# Which table contains all of the module permission data?

Tags: 7, users

I'm coming into an existing project and the previous developer totally messed up the site. There was a custom module made for a custom field and it shows up in the People > Permissions page. I cannot set this new entity type to Viewable by anonymous users via the gui interface. I would need to go into the database to make this change. Which tables do I need to look at to find this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the permission data via drush command line. I first had to find the permission name by right click the checkbox on the module page and inspect element, in my case it was **3[view any office office]**

The table responsible for permissions is: **role_permission**

I then goto the terminal and insert the following query:

```
drush sqlq 'insert into role_permission values(3,"view any office office", "office")'
```

3 is the role number then the name of the permission (view any office office) and then the module name (office).